# How to sync subtitle from DVD to Bluray

Tags: video, dvd, subtitles, blu-ray

If i have .srt subtitle for DVDrip movie .

Is there any tool or program to sync it to work properly with the same movie in bluray format ?

I'm not professional in this field so i want the most efficient and easiest way to do that .

Comment: Both movies have the same duration? Sometimes Bluray movies are extended versions with never released scenes. My recommendation is to look for and download the appropiate subtitles from www.opensubtitles.org

Comment: @jcbermu:yes they have the exact same duration

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.uruworks.net/descripcion.html).

- If the subtitles file keeps a constant *lag* or *lead* during all the movie, you can adjust it easily with this tool.
- In the case that the *lag* or *lead* keeps increasing during the movie then the framerates don't match. You have to check the framerate of your video (Usually can be 23.976 or 24 or 25 fps) and with Subtitle Workshop set the same framerate for the .srt file.

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-sync subtitles and the same duration most likely mean they are for a video with different frame rate. You can try automatically adjusting them using [alass](https://github.com/kaegi/alass):

```
alass video.mp4 out-of-sync-subtitles.srt synced-subtitles.srt
```